# java File.listFiles() on Windows OS not logically sequential

Tags: java, windows

Maybe this has been answered before, but I was not able to find it. Basicly this is the problem. I have a list of image files in a directory. They are numbered from 1-n where n -s greater than 10. In my program I create a file object pointing to the directory the files are in, and then call "listFiles()" on the file object. It returns the files, but in the following order:

```
filename1.jpg
filename10.jpg
filename11.jpg
...
filename2.jpg
filename20.jpg
filename21.jpg
...
```

Is this the OS reporting the file like this? How Do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Why don't you just sort a file list with your own comparator as you want it to be sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation clearly states

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

So you should simply not rely on this. You could sort them if you want to get always the same order, using:

```
Arrays.sort(Object[] object);
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing what you suggested. Why does MS OS report the file list that way. Is there any reason?

Comment: @Gerrie, "." comes earlier in the ASCII table than any digits, so "1.jpg" comes before than "10.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

just use `java.util.Collections.sort(list, comparator)` and implement your own `java.util.Comparator` if you don't like how it's sorted. I think it depends on OS how files are sorted in that array.

Comment: `listFiles` returns an array and not a list

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: Making a list out of an array isn't rocket sience. Arrays.asList()

Comment: @Korinna, sure but you use unecessary extra ressources and operations, while Arrays provide a direct way to sort arrays. And if you don't want to impact calling code you will need to convert your list back to an array.

Answer (score 2):

It seems ok. Try numbering them with leading zeroes, i.e. filename001.jpg.

By ok I mean that the OS is returning them in an alphabetical (technically ASCII char code) order.

EDIT: As others have pointed out, the best way to do it is to sort it by yourself. This way you won't rely on any unspecified behaviour. I provided an example how to do it with regex matching:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> toSort = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{
                    "filename1.jpg",
                    "filename11.jpg",
                    "filename2.jpg",
                    "filename21.jpg",}));

        System.out.println(toSort);
        Collections.sort(toSort, new Comparator<String>() {

            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("filename(\\d+)\\.jpg");

            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                Matcher matA = pat.matcher(a);
                Matcher matB = pat.matcher(b);
                matA.find();
                matB.find();
                String ga = matA.group(1);
                String gb = matB.group(1);
                return Integer.valueOf(ga).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(gb));
            }
        });
        System.out.println(toSort);
    }
}
```

It returns:

```
[filename1.jpg, filename11.jpg, filename2.jpg, filename21.jpg]
[filename1.jpg, filename2.jpg, filename11.jpg, filename21.jpg]
```

Comment: Its a nice idea, but the program generating the files has no option to do that. And manually renaming the files is not feasible as there are too many of them.

Comment: Ok, so you can implement a suitable comparator and sort it.

Comment: You have to sort the file list anyway. This operation doesn't place files in any order (see answer from Guillaume Polet). It doesn't matter how you name them.

Answer (score 1):

As 'listFiles()' documentation says:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

So you can name them as Rekin says and then sort those file names.